# Jquery UI Accordion focus on focus first input in active content

Tags: jquery-ui, input, focus, accordion

how can focus on first input in active content when it changed ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.newPanel).find("input:first").focus();
    }
});
```

Originally answer was based on the [jQuery Accordion Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change), but the API has changed in the meantime.

Comment: Another way to to focus on a head of accordion is  `change:function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.newHeader.length) jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:jQuery(ui.newHeader).offset().top });

            }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with JQuery UI control and I had a trouble with focusing the first input of my page. Here is the solution:

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#dvCreateItem").find("input:first").focus(); }, 1000);
```